# html submit button

Tags: php, html, button, submit, form-submit

i have this code

1. file search.php

`<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script>


</script>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['bt_submit'])){
header('Location: accueil.php?region='); 
}


?>

<style>
body {
background-image: url(../images/paper_03.png);
}
form {
background-image: url(../images/paper_02.png);
}
</style>
</head>


<body>
<form name="search" method="post"   >
                          <form name="map" style="position: relative; top:10px; left:300px; width: 400px; height: 130px;">
jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj
                           </form>
                           <form name="advanced" style="position: relative; top:10px; left:300px; width: 400px; height: 130px;" action="blabla.php">
                                                     <form name="location" style="position: relative; top:10px; left:300px; width: 300px; height: 90px;">
                                                                          <div style="background-color:99FFFF"><font color="blue">Location</font></div>
                                                                          <table>
                                                                                   <tr>
                                                                                        <td>Region:   </td><td  ><select style="width:200px" name="region"> 
                                                                                                                <option value="1">truc</option> 
                                                                                                                <option value="1">truc</option> 
                                                                                                                <option value="1">truc</option> 
                                                                                                                </select>  </td>
                                                                                   </tr>
                                                                                   <tr>
                                                                                        <td>City:   </td><td colspan="3"><input type="text" style="width:200px" name="city" />   </td>
                                                                                   </tr>
                                                                                   <tr>
                                                                                        <td>State/Province:   </td><td colspan="3"><select style="width:200px"> 
                                                                                                                <option value="1">truc</option> 
                                                                                                                <option value="1">truc</option> 
                                                                                                                <option value="1">truc</option> 
                                                                                                                </select>  </td>
                                                                                   </tr>
                                                                                   <tr>
                                                                                         <td>Country:   </td><td colspan="3"><select style="width:200px" > 
                                                                                                                <option value="1">truc</option> 
                                                                                                                <option value="1">truc</option> 
                                                                                                                <option value="1">truc</option> 
                                                                                                                </select>  </td>
                                                                                   </tr>


                                                                          </table>
                                                       </form>





                                                     <form name="keywords" style="position: relative; top:10px; left:300px; width: 400px; height: 50px;" >
                                                                           <div style="background-color:99FFFF"><font color="blue">Keywords</font></div>
                                                                            <table>
                                                                                   <tr>
                                                                                        <td colspan="2">Keywords:    </td><td ><input type="text" style="width:225px" name="keywords"  />   </td>
                                                                                   </tr>
                                                                            </table>       
                                                      </form>



                                                      <form name="company" style="position: relative; top:10px; left:300px; width: 400px; height: 50px;" >
                                                                            <div style="background-color:99FFFF"><font color="blue">Company</font></div>
                                                                            <table>
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td>Company:   </td><td colspan="3"><select style="width:230px"> 
                                                                                                                <option value="1">truc</option> 
                                                                                                                <option value="1">truc</option> 
                                                                                                                <option value="1">truc</option> 
                                                                                                                </select>  </td>
                                                                                   </tr>
                                                                            </table>
                                                       </form>



                                                       <form name="job_category"  style="position: relative; top:10px; left:300px; width: 400px; height: 50px;">
                                                                            <div style="background-color:99FFFF"><font color="blue">Job category</font></div>
                                                                            <table>
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td>Job category:   </td><td colspan="3"><select style="width:210px"> 
                                                                                                                <option value="1">truc</option> 
                                                                                                                <option value="1">truc</option> 
                                                                                                                <option value="1">truc</option> 
                                                                                                                </select>  </td>
                                                                                   </tr>
                                                                            </table>
                                                       </form>



                                                       <form name="dates"  style="position: relative; top:10px; left:300px; width: 400px; height: 50px;">
                                                                            <div style="background-color:99FFFF"><font color="blue">Dates</font></div>
                                                                            <table>
                                                                                    <tr>
                                                                                        <td>Date range:   </td><td colspan="3"><select style="width:225px"> 
                                                                                                                <option value="1">truc</option> 
                                                                                                                <option value="1">truc</option> 
                                                                                                                <option value="1">truc</option> 
                                                                                                                </select>  </td>
                                                                                   </tr>
                                                                            </table>      
                                                        </form>






                           </form>
                            <input type="submit"  name="bt_submit"  value="Search Now" style="position: relative;  left:400px; width: 100px" />


</form>
</body>
</html>`

this file contains php and html code .the interface contains two sections : the first is a form and the second is a set of forms that must be submitted by the button 
my problem is when i click in button of submit to validate the form the redirection didn't work and nothing is done. so i need know

1. why?
2. how can i fix this error?

Comment: For one... can forms be nested within forms like that??  If they can, that seems like a terrible idea to me.  Also, make sure the submit button is within the form that you want submitted.

Comment: what do you have the indentation set to ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one `<form>`. You might want to use `<fieldset>` elements to group sections of the form together, but by having multiple forms they are treated completely separately.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['bt_submit'])){
header('Location: accueil.php?region='); 
}
?>
```

Place this code on TOP of your page, even before one single alphabet of html. Header does not work when something has already been displayed

Answer (score 0):

You can not have nested forms. Plus each input is apparently a different form in your code. You will have to update it to have it in single form.